# How do I center a text inside a chain relative to the whole screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I want to create a user name centered `TextView` with an edit button to the right of the screen. If I specify the `TextView` to match the start/end of the parent, it will center. However, the text will overflow and paint over the button. I can chain one side of the text to the button, but then the text will not be centered. Here is the example code I have where `tvName` is not centered due to the button in the horizontal chain:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/pt_name_font_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvUserMsisdn"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/ibChangeName"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/aivProfile"
            tools:text="B"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/pt_name_font_size"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvUserMsisdn"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvName"
            tools:text="A"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibChangeName"
            android:layout_width="28dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_margin"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/tvName"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/tvName"
            android:background="@android:color/black"/>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: Misaligned text views]

I can't use a horizontal bias, since the button has to remain with a static size, and the width of the screen may vary, as well as the size of the font. Ideally, I would be able to specify two `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf` attributes, one for the whole width of the screen, so the text remains centered, and another one for the button, so it won't overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ideally, I would be able to specify two `app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf` attributes

I'm sure you already know this, but that is impossible.

The only thing you can do that is like that is to use a `Barrier`, but that's not helpful here because (in this case) that would be functionally identical to simply constraining the end to the start of the `ImageButton`.

The best thing you can do here, in my opinion, is to constrain the `TextView`'s start and end to the parent, and then use padding to make sure that long text doesn't overlap the `ImageButton`. The button has a fixed width (28dp), and a fixed margin (`@dimen/default_margin`), so you can give the `TextView` left/right padding equal to 28dp + 2x `default_margin`. This will make sure that text wraps at least `default_margin` away from the left edge of the `ImageButton`.

Comment: Alternatively, you could place a guideline 28dp + 1x `default_margin` from the left side of the parent, and then center the `TextView` between the `ImageButton` and the guideline with a `default_margin` on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

Put both the TextView and the ImageButton inside a RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ibChangeName"
        android:textSize="@dimen/pt_name_font_size"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="A"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibChangeName"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_margin"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This attribute for the TextView 
`android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ibChangeName"`  
ensures that the TextView won't overlap with the ImageButton  
Now you have to center the relative layout

Answer (score 0):

If the `ImageButton` always has a fixed size (28dp in this case) you can use a `Space` widget with the same dimensions as the button and place it on the left edge of the parent. You can then chain the three `Views` together and set the chain's style to `spread_inside`. The `TextView's` width can be set to `match_constraint` and its gravity to center or use `wrap_content` and `app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"` so it doesn't overlap the other `Views` if it gets too big.

Example XML to get the general idea:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/textview"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Textview"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/button"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/space" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textview" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```